# Passing a js var into jquery action as attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var temp="path.png"
```

How can I pass temp var into the jquery function as shown below

```
$('#mapfoto').prepend('<img id="theImg"  src="http://path.gr/"+temp />')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use correct quotes placement in string concatenation:

```
$('#mapfoto').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="http://path.gr/' + temp + '" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mapfoto').prepend('<img id="theImg"  src="http://path.gr/' + temp + '" />');
```